# How to prove this statement with "first" principle of Mathematical induction and not strong Mathematical induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction, exponential-function

> Define a sequence $s_0,s_1,s_2,...$ as follows :
>   $$s_0=0, s_1=4, s_k=6s_{k-1} - 5s_{k-2} \; \forall \; \text{integers} \; k\ge 2.$$ Prove by Principle of strong mathematical induction that $$s_n=5^n-1 \; \forall \; n\ge 0.$$

It's very easy to prove this by strong mathematical induction. However I am interested in proving this by "first" principle of mathematical induction only. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the "first principle of induction" ?

Comment: There is a proof without induction.

Comment: Just let $P(n)$ represent the claim: "$s_{n-1}=5^{n-1}-1$ **and** $s_n=5^n-1$.

Comment: Just show that $t_n=5^n-1$ satisfies the recursion and has the correct initial condition.  Then use induction to show that this implies that $s_n=t_n$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs This seems good idea. I will try.

Comment: @lulu Didn't get you. How to show that $t_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I am interested only in induction and that too "first" principle.

Comment: @Peter By "first" principle I mean the inductive step being $P(k)$ is true implies $P(k+1)$ is true.

Comment: Just show that $t_n=6t_{n-1}-5t_{n-2}$.  That is, $5^n-1 = 6\times (5^{n-1}-1)-5\times (5^{n-2}-1)$ (which is clearly true).

Comment: You can simulate strong induction using ordinary induction. If you want to show $\forall n.P(n)$ by strong induction on $n$, you can simulate this by instead proving $\forall m.\forall n.n \le m \to P(n)$ by ordinary induction on $m$.  (Edit: Oops, I'm late to the party.)

Comment: @ikdc see my answer below. That's what I have done. $\smile$

Comment: @GTonyJacobs +1 Very clever indeed!

Comment: The question as written is self-contradictory; where it says "for all k >= 0" it should say instead "for all k >= 2".

Comment: @Hammerite Fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$s_k-s_{k-1}=5(s_{k-1}-s_{k-2}),$$
which says that
$$s_k-s_{k-1}=4\cdot5^{k-1}$$ 
for all $k\geq1$.

Now, we can use an induction, which you wish.

For $k=0$ and for $k=1$ it's true.

Let $s_k=5^k-1$ for all $k\geq0$.

Thus, $$s_{k+1}=s_k+4\cdot5^k=5^k-1+4\cdot5^k=5^{k+1}-1.$$
Done!

Comment: How did you check that for $k=0$? If I put $k=1$ then I can only see that $s_1 - s_0=4.$ What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: @Mathmore $s_0=5^0-1$. Remember, we need to prove that $a_n=5^n-1$.

Comment: @Mathmore I think now it's not relevant because your problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

It seems I have got my answer. I saw a proof that "first" principle of mathematical induction and the strong principle of mathematical induction are equivalent. So by that proof I have formulated a proof for this one too. Here it goes :

Let $P(n) : s_n=5^n-1$

Let $Q(n) : P(j) \; \text{is true} \; \forall \; 0\le j\le n.$ We will use $Q(n)$ for using "first" principle of mathematical induction.

**Basis step :** We show that $Q(1)$ is true i.e. $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ are true statements.

Here $s_0=5^0-1=0$ which agrees with the definition $s_0=0.$
and $s_1=5^1-1=4$ which also agrees with the definition $s_1=4$.

**Inductive step :** Suppose $Q(k)$ is true for any integer $k \ge 1.$ i.e. $P(j) \; \text{is true} \; \forall \; 0\le j \le k$ for any integer $k\ge 1$.

Consider $s_{k+1}=6s_k - 5s_{k-1}.$

Then $s_{k+1}=6(5^k-1)-5(5^{k-1} -1)=6.5^k-6-5^k+5=5^{k+1}-1.$ Which was to be proved.